# If you have data with the same endianness as the system, can you simply 1-1 map bytes into an integer type?

Tags: c#, endianness

I am writing a class which lets me convert between bytes and the various integer data types. Instead of reversing arrays and then converting data, I have opted to determine if the endianness of the system is the same as the data. If it is, I simply map the data to the integer, like this in the case of a 64-bit integer:

```
result = (long)(
    (buffer[index] << 56) |
    (buffer[index + 1] << 48) |
    (buffer[index + 2] << 40) |
    (buffer[index + 3] << 32) |
    (buffer[index + 4] << 24) |
    (buffer[index + 5] << 16) |
    (buffer[index + 6] << 8) |
    (buffer[index + 7]));
```

And if the endianness of the system and data differ, it would be reversed like so:

```
result = (long)(
    (buffer[index]) |
    (buffer[index + 1] << 8) |
    (buffer[index + 2] << 16) |
    (buffer[index + 3] << 24) |
    (buffer[index + 4] << 32) |
    (buffer[index + 5] << 40) |
    (buffer[index + 6] << 48) |
    (buffer[index + 7] << 56));
```

`result` is a 64-bit signed integer

`buffer` is a byte array

`index` is a 32-bit signed integer indicating the position in the buffer to begin reading

My question is...  am I doing this wrong or is this just a really simple way to do the conversion without having to reverse the array in place or make copies?

This seems like it should work for all combinations of system and data endianness and convert between the two correctly.

Is there perhaps a different way that may be easier to read or generally more simple?

Comment: Your code has a bug - you need to upcast *before* shifting by more than 31, otherwise the shiftcount will be reduced modulo 32.

Comment: Your examples have fixed endianness (big for the first piece, little for the second), so why do you need to determine system endianness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main scenarios when converting between integers and their byte representation:

### Native endianness

This is typically the case when interoperating with native code. Use code that naturally uses native endianness, such as `Buffer.BlockCopy`, `BitConverter.ToBytes`/`ToInt64` and unsafe code. In some cases the p/invoke marshaller can do most of the work for you.

### Fixed endianness

This is typically the case when parsing files or network protocols. In that case your code pieces (minus the casting bug) are the ideal way to handle it. Give them a name that mentions the endianness, such as `ToInt64BitEndian`.

They are easy to understand, easy to test (don't depend on system endianness) and reasonably fast.

Occasionally it can give a performance boost to use `Buffer.BlockCopy` or unsafe reinterpret casting, but I'd only use those after profiling that indicates a bottleneck in this code. In my programs this has never been a bottle-neck, so I use code pretty similar to your examples.

I don't like reversing based code for this, since the code path for big-endian systems won't get exercised on a typical little-endian system.

---

ErrataRob's [code review of silent circle](http://erratasec.blogspot.de/2013/02/silent-circle-and-inexperienced.html) makes a similar point, elaborating a bit more:

> Protocol parsing is CPU independent. There is never a reason to do something different depending upon the CPU.
>
> ### Casting and byte-swapping
>
> The mistake of doing an `#if` conditional above comes from trying to fix an underlying mistake of casting between `char*` and `int*`. This is a common technique taught in your “UNIX Network Programming” class. It’s also wrong. You should never do it when parsing packets.
>
> There are two reasons to avoid this. The first is that (as mentioned above) some CPUs, such as SPARC and some versions of ARM crash when referencing unaligned integers. This makes network code unstable on RISC systems, because most integers are usually aligned anyway, meaning a lot of alignment issues escape undetected into shipping code. The only way to make stable code is to stop casting integers in network (or file) parsers.
>
> The second problem is that it causes confusion with byte-order/endianess that doesn’t happen if you just don’t cast integers. Consider the IP address “10.1.2.3”. There are only two forms for this number, either an integer with the value of `0x0a010203`, or an array of bytes with the value 0a 01 02 03. The problem is that little endian machines are weird. The integer `0x0a010203` is represented internally as `03 02 01 0a` on x86 processors, with the order of bytes “swapped”.
>
> But this is just an internal detail that YOU NEVER NEED TO WORRY ABOUT. As long as you never cross the streams and cast from a `char*` to an `int*` (or the reverse), then the byte-order/endianness never matters.

Comment: So essentially since my network protocol defines that all values are in little endian (since most systems I am dealing with will be little endian), it's a pretty good solution. On average, it won't exercise the "unmatched endianness" code path, but there's no reversal taking place when it does, meaning there is no performance loss between platforms. Additionally it's not system dependent and is easy to understand. I think this is the take away from your detailed comment, with a few other points.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of C# (.NET 5+, Core 2.x, and Core 3.x) you can use `System.Buffers.Binary.BinaryPrimitives` both to reverse the bytes of integers (`ReverseEndianness`) and also to read/write integers from/to memory in a chosen endianness.

It seems that [currently](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgCEBXAMy5il3YBLAHbYoATwDcNYgGYmpBgGEGAbxoNNTeRwA2EYQHMGAWQAUAZQAO2YQB5g4jDAB8DBAEo1Grb+IB2BjYRMXEABShBfEEMQQA3GAEAJRhsABMAVQBJYQxUYMMAUWE0wVszT2lqXwBfH0167QY9A2MTUksbe0dnN09vat8tAKCQiQiomPjElhSE/hhi0tthRNwzYNFxyOjYhOTUzJy8lAAZGIxdRZKy4QqPDyraxsa5JhRTWU7bBydXdzQzX0RgY4i86kGQ1GW3COym+xYAHVIs5srlUOcMJdrss7ghAZtQhNdtMDvNcDjbqtcOswY9GnVIQxXvJiB8TChvt0/n1AS0QWCBlDNITtpM9jNkTEYGiTgUlrcKoCwU8tIyakA), Core CLR 7.0.222.60605 does use the [movbe](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movbe) instruction to implement big-endian reads from memory (even when the C# code expresses that as a little-endian read followed by `ReverseEndianness`) but uses `bswap` and a normal `mov` to implement a big-endian store. `bswap` + `mov` is not *bad* though, especially on current Intel processors which seem to implement `movbe` [that way anyway](https://uops.info/html-instr/MOVBE_M64_R64.html) (64-bit `bswap` costs 2 µops and Ice Lake for example implements a `movbe m64, r64` with 2 extra µops compared to a normal store).

---

This part still applies to old versions of C# and may be of general interest, but is out-of-date for newer versions of C#.

Instead of reversing the array, you can reverse the `long` (well it's slightly easier with an `ulong`):

```
ulong raw = BitConverter.ToUInt64(array, pos);
if (wrong_endian)
{
    // swap groups of 4
    raw = (raw >> 32) | (raw << 32);
    // swap groups of 2
    raw = ((raw >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) | ((raw << 16) &0xFFFF0000FFFF0000);
    // swap groups of 1
    raw = ((raw >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) | ((raw << 8) & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00);
}
```

Code wasn't tested, but you get the idea. Reverse the integer instead of the array.

Comment: What's the advantage of this over the OP's code? It's harder to test(depends on system endianness), harder to understand and slower.

Comment: @CodesInChaos well he asked for it.. the array isn't copied or reversed in-place, and it's a little simpler than what he had. OP did not list performance as a requirement.

Comment: @CodesInChaos well then OP can choose not to use it, what's the problem?

Comment: Looks interesting and I wouldn't have thought of this. It meets my criteria, too. It actually helped me with a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class you can use readily.

Here is an example directly from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx).

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first), 
// reverse the byte array. 
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
// Output: int: 25
```

Comment: While this is far more simple, it doesn't quite do what I need. I should have clarified further that I specifically am seeking a solution that does not copy the array and does not reverse the array (it can treat the data in reverse, but not alter the position of the data).

Comment: Then you can use a copy of the array (with Clone() for example), if you do not find it too costly. Obviously it will take longer than your code does, but i think it will be more readable. Its a choice that we confront everyday, speed vs readability

Comment: I really like that you mention speed and readability is typically a trade off. It's quite true and in this case, I am trying to compromise between a not so speed related issue and readability. The system I am working with actually prohibits modification of the array and is also quite memory constrained, so it's more of an environmental restriction than a speed issue. I like using `BitConverter` when these constraints are not in place, aside from the fact that `BitConverter.GetBytes` will produce a new array on each call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it correctly. (except for the bug mentioned in the comment)

The code is very simple, but maybe not short. If you want fewer lines, this would do:

```
result = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    result |= (long)buffer[index + i] << (8*i);
```

And hope the compiler does loop unrolling. Similar for the other code:

```
result = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    result |= (long)buffer[index + i] << (56 - 8*i);
```

Comment: Performance isn't such a big issue and I think that doing the steps individually is more readable since you have less arithmetic per line that you have to look at. Personal opinion I suppose, but thanks for confirming and providing an alternative!